# Ubuntu Server 12.04 connected to internet via adsl router with cable eth0. How can i share this connection

Tags: server, internet

I have an Ubuntu Server 12.04 connected to internet via adsl router with cable eth0.

The Ubuntu Server has the static ip 192.168.10.33

The adsl router (as DNS) has the ip 192.168.10.254 which I set as gateway in /etc/network/interfaces.

I want another Ubuntu (laptop), with ip 192.168.10.1 with wlan0 to connect to internet **through the Ubuntu Server** and not through the adsl router (which is easy).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the server as a router. This is kinda complex, but not impossible. depends on how dedicated you are. in order for this to work, your server will need a second network card. bridge eth0 to eth1: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge

you will need then a WAP (wireless access point), http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122013

configure your wap with setting from your router, and use eth1 to plug it in. you now have a wap plugged into eth1, which is bridged to eth0.

there is much more that will be involved with configuring, but this is the basic model.

good luck!